# Can spring boot applications deployed on a tomcat server use a common connection pooling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, connection-pooling, object-pooling

When multiple spring boot applications created and deployed to a tomcat server. Is it possible to use a common connection pooling, datasource instead of providing these details in application.properties file. Or does this already taken care within the spring boot implementation

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy multiple application then each application manages it connection pool. 

Spring boot boundary is limited to each application context and it does not know what other application deployed and which db they are using.

Comment: I was asking if we can have connection pool at the server level and get connections from the pool to use within the application. Like we create a data source at the server level accessing it through JNDI and use connections from the pool across various applications in general in application servers